# At java graphics2d bufferedimage is blurry on upscaled (factor 1.5) highdpi screen

Tags: java, bufferedimage, blurry, highdpi

I'm writing a software using text and some graphics displayed at the gui using swing graphics2d. At the beginning text and graphics were blurry, because scaling (windows 10) of highdpi screen is factor 1.5.

After some research I got the text crispy using setRenderingHints and the graphics get fine, when changing the properties of the final software:
HighDpi Settings manually to 'system' (windows 10).

But I would like to get smooth graphics wothout the user to change the properties of the software manually.
Already I tried all types of BufferedImages existing and all types of getScaledInstance. Additionally (that's not a java problem, it may be a different question) I tried to set the HighDpi settings of the software using a windows manifest file, but it doesn't take over the settings.

This helped to get the text at graphics2d crispy:

```
Map<?, ?> desktopHints =  (Map<?, ?>)      
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints");
    if (desktopHints != null) 
    {
        g2d.setRenderingHints(desktopHints);
    }
```

But to get graphics fine was not possible:

```
BufferedImage imgOrig = ImageIO.read(song.getFigure());
     Image scaledImage = imgOrig.getScaledInstance(-1, 300, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
     g2d.drawImage(scaledImage , leftValue, heightValue, this);
```

As already told I changed imgOrig to all existing types of BufferedImages and tried all scaling types but none helps

This helped to get graphics smooth:
Override HighDpi Settings of final program manually to 'system'

To get this behaviour automatically I included a program.exe.manifest

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
            <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware> <!-- fallback for Windows 7 and 8 -->
            <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">system</dpiAwareness> 
       </windowsSettings>
    </application>
```

which is accepted and doesn't throw any error, but HighDpi settings aren't as desired.

Goal is to get the same behaviour automatically as if highdpi settings are overridden manually.

Comment: What Java are you using? It's important. Java 8 doesn't do HiDPI (you are on your own) but SWING in Java 9 and up *try* to do HiDPI but fail at it in several places, breaking even VM backwards compatibility with Java 8 class files.

Comment: Rather than scaling the image yourself, have you tried using [the 4-int drawImage method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,int,int,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) so the Graphics instance does the scaling?

Comment: I am using java version 10.

Comment: To the second remark, thank you for the idea! i haven't seen this method yet, but the result is still same blurry

Comment: If I could upload a picture, I would present the results.  Best is using the BufferedImage.getScaledInstance(-1, imgHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); AND setting the high dpi props of the exe or jar file manually to system. Second ist using the 4-int method mentioned from VGR (but don't change the high dpi settings to system or it will be blurry again). All other methods described here will result into a blurry picture